How to extract the title-Tag in a Table-Element
I am working on a Flutter-App presenting Chart values of my stock. Technically this is done by extracting the values through the element by id.
e.g.
<td id="delta" class="longprice flop" title="Close 2,635">-10,25%</td>

The example contains the element-id "delta" with value -10,25%. This is perfectly done with
String? delta = document.getElementById('delta')?.innerHtml.toString();

Unfortunately I am unable to retrieve the title-value, in this example "Close 2,635".
Question is how to retrieve the content "Close 2,635" within Flutter.
var collection = document.getElementsByClassName('longprice flop');
for (var i = 0; i < collection.length; i++) {
  print( 'i=$i - ${collection[i].attributes!}' );
}

this produces the following output - title is missing :-(
i=0 - {id: delta, class: flop longprice}


Not familiar with Flutter and just a guess: Do you have a script that removes title in order to display a fancy tool tip instead of the default tool tip that title provides?

If so, I could easily use the title before removing it. I don't know anything about such a script.
